# knowing when a parameter is updated

Tags: ros, nodehandle, parameter-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Parameter%20Server%20API
or from the NodeHandle API (the getParamCached methods) we see that it is possible to have a parameter cached and updated locally on changes.
Does the API provide a way to attach a callback function to these updates?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42733/knowing-when-a-parameter-is-updated/) by [fabiodl](https://answers.ros.org/users/3097/fabiodl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2012-08-31

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PerkinsJames](https://answers.ros.org/users/2621/perkinsjames/) on 2012-08-31**:
This would be useful for me, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think so. You have to use `getParamCached()` each time you want to use the value (no messages are sent by that method).

[Dynamic reconfigure](http://ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure) provides an alternate API which *does* provide a callback. That may be better for your use case.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fabiodl](https://answers.ros.org/users/3097/fabiodl/) on 2012-08-31**:
Sorry, I edit my question, with getCached   I meant getParamCached

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-07-02**:
Added to : http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Patterns/Parameterization#A.22Cached.22_Access_to_the_Parameter_Server